# Making textboxes in photoshop

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, photoshop

So I have been trouble thinking of a way to ask this question so I will just tell what I have done and what I want to do.

I created a simple design in Photoshop for a web page with a navbar and login field. I sliced the images I needed to and saved into my site folder as html and images. I opened up dreamweaver and opened that file. The web page looks great but I cant enter text into the text boxes because they are just images. So my question is how do I make those text-box images real textboxes without losing their design and font style?

My Web Programming Experience level: I have programming experience in HTML and CSS and some PHP.

Comment: There's no programming question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `backgroung-image` property, for example:
In your html/php file:

```
<div class="box">
contents here
</div>
```

In your css file:

```
.box
{
background-image:url('image.jpg');
font-family: yourFont;
}
```

Comment: To expand on kelsar's answer, you may need to add some `padding` style attributes to accommodate your design.  Also, you can use `<textarea class="box"></textarea>` in lieu of a `<div>`, as kelsar suggests.

Comment: You still can't type into your div

Comment: ty guys for the help, I am just ridding of the premade html file photoshop made and redoing it myself with the slices I made.

Answer (score 0):

If you want HTML-fields, where people can enter stuff into, then you need to make a form (something like this):

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="someClass" />
</form>
```

Then you can add a background to that, with your images, like Kelsar wrote.

```
.box
{
background-image:url('image.jpg');
font-family: yourFont;
}
```

So start by building it in HTMl and thereafter make it look sweet and neat with the CSS. If you don't have any experience with HTML-forms, then you can read about there here: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php

Good luck. I hope it helped.